# How to capture the whitespace before the first "{" in the data?

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to capture the first whitespace before the first `{` for every line that begins with `add`:

```
add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}
add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}

   {(?<=\W)
```

Would that do the trick? I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: Try `(?<=^add) (?={)` https://regex101.com/r/HKU9dp/1 or use a capturing group `^add(\s+){` https://regex101.com/r/50NfuR/1

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern `{(?<=\W)` you will only match the `{` because the lookbehind assertion `(?<=\W)` is true as `{` is a non word character.

---

If you want to use the lookaround after matching `{` you could capture the space in a capturing group and assert what is on the left is the start of the string, then `add {`

```
( ){(?<=^add {)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rAiHZQ/1)

Another way to use it as a capturing group could be matching `add` first

```
^add( ){
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y10nGn/1)

Using lookarounds you could get a match only instead of a capturing group by asserting the start of the string followed by `add` on the left and assert `{` on the right while matching the space in between.

```
(?<=^add) (?={)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKU9dp/1)

Comment: This is the actual data 

add {"id":1,"last":"Doe","first":"John","location":{"city":"Oakland","state":"CA","postalCode":"94607"},"active":true}

add {"id":2,"last":"Doe","first":"Jane","location":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postalCode":"94105"},"active":true}
add {"id":3,"last":"Black","first":"Jim","location":{"city":"Spokane","state":"WA","postalCode":"99207"},"active":true}
add {"id":4,"last":"Frost","first":"Jack","location":{"city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postalCode":"98204"},"active":false}
get {"location":{"state":"WA"},"active":true}
get {"id":1}
get {"active":true}

Comment: @PraketaSaxena Can you update this link https://regex101.com/r/eF8ZGP/1 with the right format of the string?